# javascript solution for max-width inside tables

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a jquery/javascript alternative to setting max-width on a image residing in a table. I can not use the css solution of display:table / table-layout:fixed because of the amount of table columns and i don't want the columns equal widths.

Here is a jsfiddle example....

http://jsfiddle.net/TAE3w/52/

In Chrome if you stretch the "result" box wide and narrow the "Google" text scales inside the table cells , but ofc in FF and IE the max-width will not work.

I need to make sure the images are never larger then their native size , while also scaling down when the table width decreases on different screen resolutions.

Can jquery/javascript find the native width and various sized images within the table , and make sure they are never larger , while also using max-width or width 100% to scale down ?

```
<table>
    <tr>
       <td>
        <div>    
            <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png"/>
            <img src="http://pictar.ru/data/media/24/nature__463_.jpg"/>
        </div>
       </td>
    </tr>
</table>

<style>
    div {
        border:2px solid red;
    }
    div img {
        max-width: 100%;
        height: auto;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: does this work for you http://jsfiddle.net/TAE3w/53/

Comment: Himanshu , that only works in Chrome. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go. The code is commented.
The idea is to make image not affect the width of the table. To achieve this, the image have been set `position: absolute`. But this creates an issue, the image do not affect the height as well. To tackle this, images have been wrapped into individual container and height of that container has been set using JavaScript.

```js
         $(function() {

           var resized = false,
             img_containers = null;

           function setImageContainerHeight() {
             if (!img_containers) {
               img_containers = $('td .img_container');
             }
             img_containers.each(function() {
               $(this).css('height', $('> img', this).height());
             });
           }

           $(window).resize(function() {
             resized = true;
           });

           /* it is better to use window.setInterval() instead of $(window).resize(function(){...})*/
           window.setInterval(function() {
             if (!resized) {
               return;
             }

             setImageContainerHeight();

             resized = false;
           }, 250);

           setImageContainerHeight();

         });
```

```css
/* table should have some width since the images are not affecting its width now */

table {
  width: 100%;
}
/* styled the div */

.img_container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
/* this way the image will not affect width of the table. instead it'll be affected by width of the parent div */

.img_container img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <!-- wrap each image in its container. Can be done in javascript/jquery if not feasible in html -->
        <div class="img_container">
          <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="img_container">
          <img src="http://pictar.ru/data/media/24/nature__463_.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Ejay , this is a perfect solution. Thanks ! Do you have an alternative script where a jquery library is not needed ? Just curious , i'm not sure the host wants to load jquery as they use mootools

Answer (score 1):

Here is the plain JavaScript version.

```js
//include this block after the markup, or wrap all of this block's JavaScript code in a function and use that a window.onload = yourfunction  

var resized = false,
  img_containers = null;

function setImageContainerHeight() {
  if (!img_containers) {
    img_containers = document.querySelectorAll('td .img_container');
  }

  Array.prototype.forEach.call(img_containers, function(elem) {
    elem.style.height = elem.querySelector(':scope > img').height + 'px';
  });
}
setImageContainerHeight();

window.onresize = function () {
  resized = true;
}

/* it is better to use window.setInterval() instead of $(window).resize(function(){...})*/
window.setInterval(function() {
  if (!resized) {
    return;
  }

  setImageContainerHeight();

  resized = false;
}, 250);

setImageContainerHeight();
```

```css
/* nothing has changed here */

/* table should have some width since it has not images affecting its width now */

table {
  width: 100%;
}
/* styled the div */

.img_container {
  border: 2px solid red;
  position: relative;
}
/* this way the image will not affect width of the table. instead it'll be affected by width of the parent div */

.img_container img {
  position: absolute;
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<!-- nothing has changed here -->
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div>
        <!-- wrap each image in its container. Can be done in javascript/jquery if not feasible in html -->
        <div class="img_container">
          <img src="https://www.google.ru/images/srpr/logo4w.png" />
        </div>
        <div class="img_container">
          <img src="http://pictar.ru/data/media/24/nature__463_.jpg" />
        </div>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: thanks , i removed the jquery you had in there "  $(window).resize(function() {  "